# Date comparison false for past year

Tags: windows, powershell, powershell-2.0

I have a small script that is recursing through a directory. Any files older than X days should be removed.

This works fine for the current year, however it is not seeing or removing files from 2013. I am thinking the date comparison between the $_.LastWriteTime and the (Get-Date).AddDays() somehow is not of the same type (or appears that way).

In my source I print the file name info instead of really remove the file for testing purposes. Also, my actual file structure looks like this when I just run:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path $myPath -Recurse -Force | % { Write-Host $_.FullName " - " $_.LastWriteTime }
```

- \MyNAS\archive  -  2/13/2014 1:01:33 PM
- \MyNAS\inbound  -  2/13/2014 12:49:32 PM
- \MyNAS\outbound  -  2/13/2014 12:45:14 PM
- \MyNAS\temp  -  2/13/2014 1:00:03 PM
- \MyNAS\archive\13090318.res  -  **9/3/2013** 11:46:28 AM
- \MyNAS\inbound\archive  -  2/13/2014 12:49:32 PM
- \MyNAS\inbound\Error  -  2/13/2014 1:01:07 PM
- \MyNAS\inbound\archive\14020445.exp  -  2/4/2014 4:26:36 PM
- \MyNAS\inbound\archive\14020449.res  -  2/4/2014 5:12:24 PM
- \MyNAS\inbound\archive\14021157.exp  -  2/11/2014 4:41:30 PM
- \MyNAS\inbound\archive\14021157.res  -  2/11/2014 4:41:31 PM
- \MyNAS\inbound\Error\13091117.tmp  -  **9/11/2013** 7:09:00 AM
- \MyNAS\inbound\Error\14021036.tmp  -  2/10/2014 2:18:10 PM
- \MyNAS\inbound\Error\14021137.tmp  -  2/11/2014 1:24:21 PM
- \MyNAS\outbound\ARCHIVE  -  2/13/2014 5:12:54 PM
- \MyNAS\outbound\ARCHIVE\13081402.tmp  -  **8/14/2013** 4:57:54 PM
- \MyNAS\outbound\ARCHIVE\14021056.csv  -  2/10/2014 2:11:32 PM
- \MyNAS\outbound\ARCHIVE\14021157.csv  -  2/11/2014 4:37:55 PM
- \MyNAS\temp\13091935.exp.tmp  -  9/19/2013 10:13:41 AM

Code:

```
param([String]$myPath="")
$limit = (Get-Date).AddDays(-33).ToShortDateString()

Write-Host "Looking in : $myPath"
Write-Host "Purging anything older than : $limit"

if ($myPath.length -gt 0) {
Get-ChildItem -Path $myPath -Recurse -Force | Where-Object { $_.LastWriteTime.ToShortDateString() -lt $limit } | % { Write-Host $_.FullName " - " $_.LastWriteTime.ToShortDateString() }
} else {
Write-Host "Source path not passed. Please pass the source path to purge"
}
```

Comment: You are using string representations of dates to compare dates. That is not a good idea. You might want to research using dates in PowerShell for better ways of doing the date comparison.

Comment: Wonderful @AndrewMorton! That is the direction I was needing. I read up on casting powershell string into datetime and vice versa and it's working now. Your note is appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem as Andrew Morton (thank you!) pointed out was I was not casting my variables correctly. Instead of comparing strings I needed to be comparing datetime variables. Here is the fixed working code :

```
param([String]$myPath="")
$limit = [datetime](Get-Date).AddDays(-33)

Write-Host "Looking in : $myPath"
Write-Host "Purging anything older than : $limit"

if ($myPath.length -gt 0) {
Get-ChildItem -Path $myPath -Recurse -Force | Where-Object { [datetime]$_.LastWriteTime -lt $limit } | % { Write-Host $_.FullName " - " $_.LastWriteTime.ToShortDateString() }
} else {
Write-Host "Source path not passed. Please pass the source path to purge"
}
```

Comment: You should be able to mark your answer as the accepted answer, which may help anyone else reading this in the future.